# AngularJS Custom Directive - bindToController Error

Tags: angularjs

Why am I getting the error: ***$ctrl is not defined*** from the custom directive below? I did define the $ctrl in the controller inside the directive.

```
    var myapp = angular.module('plunker', []);
myapp.directive('userinfo', function() {
    return{
      restrict:'E',
      template: 'User : <b>{{$ctrl.user.firstName}}</b> <b>{{$ctrl.user.lastName}}</b>',
      scope:{
        user: '='
      },
      bindToController:true, 
      controller:function(){
        var $ctrl = this; 

      },

      controllerAs:$ctrl
    }
    return directive;
});
myapp.controller("MyController", function() {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.jakob = {};
    $ctrl.jakob.firstName = "Jakob";
    $ctrl.jakob.lastName  = "Jenkov";

    $ctrl.john = {};
    $ctrl.john.firstName = "John";
    $ctrl.john.lastName  = "Doe";
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`controllerAs` should be string, but you are passing the global variable $ctrl which is not defined. Try this:

```
controllerAs: '$ctrl'
```

[From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> If it is necessary to reference the controller or any functions bound
>   to the controller from the template, you can use the option
>   controllerAs to specify the name of the controller as an alias.